# A2DP drops when trying to BluetoothSocket.connet() in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm, avrcp

So I am working with a hardware device that utilizes A2DP, HFP, AVRCP, and SPP. The problem I am getting seems to be only on some phones but I want to resolve it.

While connecting the hardware device through Android (pair.connect) everything works fine. If I go into a default music player it streams correctly as well as AVRCP commands working.

However, in the app I am working on I use SPP. And when I try to use the BluetoothSocket.connet() method it causes the hardware to lose A2DP and AVRCP (media connections) I am using the standard bluetoothSerialService class from the Bluetooth Chat example

```
private static final UUID SerialPortServiceClass_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

...

```
mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SerialPortServiceClass_UUID);
mmSocket.connect();
```

The phones that don't work and I am testing include Droid X (2.2/2.3), HTC Desire 2.2, Droid1 2.2. And it works on Samsung Captivate 2.2 and LG Optimus One 2.2

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I've noticed bluetooth audio dropping out on my laptop when using a bluetooth mouse, so maybe its just badly implemented bluetooth stacks?

Comment: would be nice to share solution with community..

Comment: It is due to poorly developed bluetooth stack..